# Hiding Super Class Methods from User of Child Class

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, oop, inheritance

I am wondering if it is possible to prevent the user from invoking the methods of a parent class when using the child class. At the same time, I do wish that these methods be available to the methods of the child class themselves.

For instance, suppose I have an implementation of a linked list. I then base a stack ADT implementation on it by inheriting (not sure if it is good design ...). Hence, I wish to "hide" the methods of LinkedList class from the user of the Stack class.

LinkedList:

```
class LinkedList(object):
    class Node(object):
        """
        Inner class of LinkedList. Contains a blueprint for a node of the LinkedList
        """
        def __init__(self, v, n=None):
            """
            Initializes a List node with payload v and link n
            """
            self.value=v
            self.next=n

    def __init__(self):
        """
        Initializes a LinkedList and sets list head to None
        """
        self.head=None

    def insert(self, v):
        """
        Adds an item with payload v to beginning of the list
        in O(1) time 
        """
        Node = self.Node(v, self.head)
        self.head = Node
        print("Added item: ", Node.value, "self.head: ", self.head.value)

    def size(self):
        """
        Returns the current size of the list. O(n), linear time
        """
        current = self.head
        count = 0
        while current:
            count += 1
            current = current.next
        return count

    def search(self, v):
        """
        Searches the list for a node with payload v. Returns the node object or None if not found. Time complexity is O(n) in worst case.
        """
        current = self.head
        found = False
        while current and not found:
            if current.value == v:
                found = True
            else:
                current = current.next
        if not current:
            return None
        return current

    def delete(self, v):
        """
        Searches the list for a node with payload v. Returns the node object or None if not found. Time complexity is O(n) in worst case.
        """
        current = self.head
        previous = None
        found = False
        while current and not found:
            if current.value == v:
                found = True
            else:
                previous = current
                current = current.next
        # nothing found, return None
        if not current:
            return None
        # the case where first item is being deleted
        if not previous:
            self.head = current.next
        # item from inside of the list is being deleted    
        else:
            previous.next = current.next

        return current

    def __str__(self):
        """
        Prints the current list in the form of a Python list            
        """
        current = self.head
        toPrint = []
        while current != None:
            toPrint.append(current.value)
            current = current.next
        return str(toPrint)
```

Stack:

```
from PythonADT.lists import LinkedList

class Stack(LinkedList):
    def __init__(self):
        LinkedList.__init__(self)
```

Comment: No, that's probably not a good design. If you don't want to expose the same interface, *compose* don't *inherit*.

Comment: If Stack isn't going to fulfill the interface promises that LinkedList makes, it should not extend LinkedList.

Comment: As described in the official Python documentation **["9.6. Private Variables"](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html?highlight=private#private-variables)**, it is possible to protected a method inside a `class`. Simply declare that function by naming it starting by twice underscores (ex: `__private_search(self):`).

Comment: @jonrsharpe are you suggesting something like this? `class Stack(object):
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.items = LinkedList()` after which I would proceed to implement the Stack ADT but using the LinkedList behind the scenes.

Comment: Yes, exactly that. Or `self._items` to indicate that the list itself is also not part of the stack's public interface.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Is this an example of composition? That is, when a class creates an instance of another class for its use?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I also used the above line as `self.__items = LinkedList()` to "hide" the `items` field from being seen by the user of the Stack class. Is this how it is done in Python?

Answer (score -1):

Here are the official syntax to declare protected and private method in a class.

1. The protected method declared in the parent class will be callable from a child class.
2. The private method declared in the parent class will be hidden from a child class.

The raised Exception is:

> `# AttributeError: '<ChildClass>' object has no attribute '__<private_function>'`

**Step 1** - declare both private and protected method in the `class Parent`.

```
class Parent(object):
    # a private method starts by 2 '_'
    def __parent_private(self):
        print('inside __parent_private()')

    # a protected method starts by 1 '_'
    def _parent_protected(self):
        print('inside _parent_protected()')
```

**Step 2** - declare function to call the both function from a `class Child`.

```
class Child(Parent):

    def call__parent_private(self):
        self.__parent_private()

    def call_parent_protected(self):
        self._parent_protected()
```

**Step 3** - create an instance of `class Child` to check private and protected accesses.

```
myChild = Child()
```

> Check of protected method from the Child class ==> Access is allowed

```
# internal access of protected method
myChild.call_parent_protected()
```

Output: "`inside _parent_protected()`"

```
# direct access of protected method
myChild._parent_protected()
```

Output: "`inside _parent_protected()`"

> Check of private method from the Child class ==> Access is denied

```
# internal access of private method
myChild.call__parent_private()
```

Error: "`AttributeError: 'Child' object has no attribute '_Child__parent_private'`"

```
# direct access of private method
myChild.__parent_private()
```

Error: "`AttributeError: 'Child' object has no attribute '__parent_private'`"